# Mystery of the invisible MsgBox 50 in AutoHotKey

Tags: sqlite, autohotkey

## The Big Mystery. Find the invisible MsgBox 50 (message box)

This Messagebox is a little different from others.

if I create a normal box with normal `MsgBox, test` and press CTRL+C from his surfice i get this:

```
---------------------------
gi-everywhere.ahk
---------------------------
test
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

but with this mysterious Message Box i got:

```
---------------------------
50
---------------------------
50
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This mysterious box missing the title.

I searched for this mysterious box for two hours (and days before). also a friend that has the script downloaded from github, got the same box, and also not found it into the source.

Today I took extra time and wanted to crack the puzzle. the whole thing recorded on video and put on YouTube.

The **best result** in the end was I could turn off the box if I **slowed down the script**. I set in about 10 tootips, each with a 2 second brake behind it.
I took the tooltips out again and the box was back again.

the script is pretty big (2.6MB), I can not put it in here into the posting.

I have already asked myself if the JetBrains might have a bug in IDEa search algorithm?
Maybe this mysterious message comes from SQLite?
any other ideas?

but of course I can give two links:
**Source:** [Release v0.98.50 on github the global-IntelliSense-everywhere](https://github.com/sl5net/global-IntelliSense-everywhere/releases/tag/v0.98.50)
**Video (2hours!)**: [Mystery of the invisible MsgBox 50 in AutoHotKey](https://youtu.be/3BH1d1k2vVw)

**Screenshot of the Box:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
msgbox,% " ERROR !Sql_Temp.valueObj `n(" A_ThisFunc " " RegExReplace(A_LineFile,".*\\") ":"  A_LineNumber ")" , 50,50
```

Once upon a time, I automatically (regex search and replace) moved some Toolboxes to relative positions 50 and 50 (`, 50,50`). Somehow an error must have happened. and messageboxes were also populated with this relative position value.

this large area became invisible:

```
" ERROR !Sql_Temp.valueObj `n(" A_ThisFunc " " RegExReplace(A_LineFile,".*\\") ":"  A_LineNumber ")"
```

and it became difficult for me to have a idear what i should search for.